# WWW Unity: not showing text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, web

I am trying to assign a text taken from a page linked to a Database through the `WWW` class to a `Text` (in the code `linguaitaliana`) that I inserted inside Unity.

Through the script I propose below, I take the name in the `Update` function and insert it into the `IEnumerator` function.

Here is my code

```
public class Prova2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    Prova script1;
    public string name;
    public Text linguaitaliana=null;
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        WWW DataIta = new WWW("http://arnaples.altavista.org/QueryTestoITA.phpnum=" +name);
        Debug.Log("http://arnaples.altavista.org/QueryTestoITA.phpnum=" +name);
        string DataString = DataIta.text;
        Debug.Log(DataString);
        linguaitaliana.text = DataString;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        script1=gameObject.GetComponent<Prova>();
        name=script1.due;
    }
}
```

`DataIta` is correct, since the link is the working one. But when I do `DataIta.text`, I don't get the text I want (it's empty!)

[image]

If I try to put the link directly (without concatenation) inside the script like

```
new WWW("http://arnaples.altavista.org/QueryTestoITA.phpnum=CasaLuigi");
//Debug.Log("http://arnaples.altavista.org/QueryTestoITA.phpnum=" +name);
```

the result is correct

[image]

Just for completion this is the setup in the Inspector

[image]

The problem is, therefore, of printing. Solutions?

Comment: Hi, please start by [edit]ting your question and post your code, as text.

Comment: Image links currupted

Comment: Should be fixed now :)

Comment: thank you. Sorry, it is my first post. I'm very sorry!

Comment: what is this `Thread.Sleep(1000)` supposed to do? Did you want to `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);` maybe?

Comment: @Luigi105: no worries, just try to fix it :-)

Comment: I edited the question for you

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues here:

First of all

> I take the name in the Update function and insert it into the IEnumerator function.

Nope! `Start` is executed before `Update` so you don't pass the name in there. Anyway it wouldn't make sense in an `Update` method which is called every frame so move it to the top of the `Start` instead.

---

Second

this `Thread.Sleep(1000);` makes no sense! I guess you ment to use [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
```

in order to wait a second.

---

Finally

You created an http request using

```
WWW DataIta = new WWW("http://arnaples.altavista.org/QueryTestoITA.phpnum=" +name);
```

but you don't wait until it is finished with downloading. You should do

```
using(WWW DataIta = new WWW("http://arnaples.altavista.org/QueryTestoITA.phpnum=" + name))
{
    yield return www;

    // use result
}
```

In general I would recommend to rather use [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) instead of `WWW` which is obsolete and might get removed in the future. And also check for download or connection errors

```
public class Prova2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    Prova script1;
    public string name;
    public Text linguaitaliana=null;
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        script1=gameObject.GetComponent<Prova>();
        name=script1.due;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        using (var webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://arnaples.altavista.org/QueryTestoITA.phpnum=" + name))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError || webRequest.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat(this, "Download error due to {0} - {1}", webRequest.responseCode, webRequest.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Download complete: " + webRequest.downloadHandler.text, this);
                linguaitaliana.text = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*